# GdkPixbuf : is it possible to change the data without instancing a new Pixbuf?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gtk3, gdkpixbuf, pixbuf

I need a Pixbuf with mutable content. This means that it needs to be updated quite fast in order to display frames with a reasonable speed.

In the python binding there is the `get_pixels` method. Is it unclear to me if I can use it to update the data in the pixbuf or not and if it returns the original data stored in memory of a copy of them.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How often is often?

Comment: @andlabs: your question is irrelevant, because the software I am working on does more to the frames than just displaying them, and my question is in the larger context of reducing the cost of every single phases of frame retrieval, manipulation and display.

Comment: @andlabs's question is quite valid. '...with a reasonable speed' is largely subjective without specification. If you're observing solar cycles, once a day could be reasonable. If you want to observe interactions of particles, your monitor will probably be to slow.

Comment: Well, working on a software that displays a video from a camera, I run on the same issue, GdkPixbuf seems impossible to modify and can only be built from bytes which is immutable. Thus, to display the image from the camera, I'm forced to make an extra copy of each image that could be avoided by working directly on the GdkPixbuf pixels.